# Advantage of Class component over react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Every where I see are the advantages of hooks over class component , but still class components in react do exist so can anyone tell me the advantages of class components over hooks?

Comment: Class components only exist in legacy code. Most of the legacy code with class components is being shifted towards functional components by companies. Every new react app in industry will always use functional components.

Comment: Readability! I find class components far easier to read and understand, with funcional components being generally a mess of nested functions. Not to mention the easier wording (`componentDidMount` vs `useEffect`), so that I would use class over functions every single time I can have a choice. That said, the whole question and this comment is 100% opinion-based.